# What is wrong with this simple JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
(1-$500.00)(2-$20.00)
```

I want to turn it into an array with values looking like this:

```
output[0] = 1-$500.00
output[1] = 2-$20.00
```

So I tried this:

```
var output = '(1-$500.00)(2-$20.00)';
var pattern = "/\\)\\(|\\(|\\)?/";

output = output.split(pattern);

alert(output);
```

But it just alerts the original string, doesn't get the job done. Is there something wrong with my regex or the way I'm using the split function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to quote regexes.

```
var pattern = /\)\(|\(|\)/;
```

---

To ensure the content follows the expected format (verification) and avoid the leading and ending empty entries, I'd use `RegExp.exec` instead of `String.split`.

```
function my_split(input) {
  var pattern = /\((\d+-\$\d+\.\d+)\)/g;
  var output = [];
  while((m = pattern.exec(input)))
     output.push(m[1]);
  return output;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me - splits the input to single characters (tested using http://writecodeonline.com/javascript/)

Comment: Seems to work (http://jsfiddle.net/XE6pQ/) but the result also includes an empty string both at the first and last index.

Comment: @polar: This can't be avoided if you use `.split`. See update for the way to avoid those 2 empty stuff in the first place using `.exec`.